# Removing suffix from list Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of packages and want to remove suffixes from specific combination of characters. 
Should I use regex or other mehotds such as replace ? All packages' endings are different because these are versions so I am not sure which to use and how. I think I should clear the remaining characters from `-0:` in string.
What list is like:

```
... 'znc-devel-0:1.4-1.el6.i686', 'znc-devel2-0:1.4-1.el6.x86_64' ...
```

What I want  to have:

```
...'znc-devel', 'znc-devel2'...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hint: Use a __loop__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`partition` on "-0" and take the left portion.

```
seq = ['znc-devel-0:1.4-1.el6.i686', 'znc-devel2-0:1.4-1.el6.x86_64']
print [item.partition("-0")[0] for item in seq]
```

Result:

```
['znc-devel', 'znc-devel2']
```

Comment: then you need to use `print [item.partition("-0:")[0] for item in seq]`

Comment: what's the difference between split and partition?

Comment: `partition` separates the string into three parts: the part before the separator, the separator, and the part after the separator. I suspect (but have not tested) that it's faster than `split`, since it only needs to scan for the first instance of the separator, instead of all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Through `re.sub` and list comprehension.

```
>>> L = ['znc-devel-0:1.4-1.el6.i686', 'znc-devel2-0:1.4-1.el6.x86_64']
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r'-0:.*', r'', line) for line in L]
['znc-devel', 'znc-devel2']
```